# How to delete lines that have no numbers?

Tags: bash, ubuntu, text, awk, notepad++

i want to delete every line have not any numbers :
input:

```
cvb
rdfgd
rgftdr 5421
dftghtd 546465
fgthyft 153
ftds
gyj
```

output:

```
rgftdr 5421
dftghtd 546465
fgthyft 153
```

Comment: Using Notepad++: Find: `^\D+(?:\R|$)`, Replace: `LEAVE EMPTY`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you please try following.

```
awk '$0 ~ /[0-9]/'  Input_file > temp_file && mv temp_file Input_file
OR
awk '/[0-9]/' Input_file > temp_file && mv temp_file Input_file
```

***EDIT:*** If any line don't have at least 2 numbers minimum then try following.

```
awk '/[0-9]{2,}/' Input_file
```

Comment: and how to save that in an output file?

Comment: @Aliemaditaj, could you please check my update and let me know then?

Comment: Same as `awk '/[0-9]/`'

Comment: other quasstion : have to deleate any line have not  2 numbers in minimum

Comment: @Aliemaditaj, one post 1 question, so please try to search forums and if you don't get anything then you could post a new question.